# Kite Client or Package Conflicts Preventing Spyder 4.0 Installation

Tags: spyder

I'm on a Widows 7 machine. I reinstalled anaconda, made a new environment and then installed spyder 4.0 using conda. The Spyder 4 dialog box briefly opens and then crashes. Anaconda prompt says that it's a type error in the kite client. Below is the full output:

```
(spyder4) C:\>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site
-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3711, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\tb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site
-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3552, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\tb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site
-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 960, in setup
    self.completions.start()
  File "C:\Users\tb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site
-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\plugin.py", line 292, in start
    client_info['plugin'].start()
  File "C:\Users\tb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site
-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\kite\plugin.py", line 144, in start
    self.client.start()
  File "C:\Users\tb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site
-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\kite\client.py", line 62, in start
    self.sig_client_started.emit(self.languages)
TypeError: KiteClient.sig_client_started[list].emit(): argument 1 has unexpected
 type 'str'
```

I also tried using miniconda and the results were the same with the type error in the KiteClient.

When I tried conda update spyder=4.0.0 in the base environment Anaconda Prompt says there's package conflicts with jupyter and qtconsole and doesn't upgrade Spyder to the new version.

I also tried conda update anaconda inside the base environment and the results were the same as above with the type error in the KiteClient.

Does anyone know how I can get Spyder 4 installed or how I can troubleshoot it? Maybe remove Kite somehow. The new version of Spyder looks really sleek, I would love to use it.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Do you have Kite installed in your system?

Comment: Yes, I have Kite installed.

Comment: Please update Kite to its latest version and try again.

Comment: I reinstalled Kite and spyder 4 and got the same type error for KiteClient.

Comment: Please post an issue about it [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues). It looks like a bug.